# How can I delete a has_many relation when update?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables, example:

```
table_one n x 1 table_two
```

However, table_two has many table_one elements.

Models:

```
class TableOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table_two
end

class TableTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tables_one, class_name 'TableOne'
end
```

I would like to auto delete all elements in `table_one` when the `table_two` update (before it)

ps: or, where is the correct place to put `table_one.table_two.delete_all`?

**UPDATE 1**

This command:

```
table_two = TableTwo.last
table_two.tables_one = [TableOne.new(<attributes>), TableOne.new(<attributes>, TableOne.new(<attributes>]
table_two.save
```

Should remove all the existing tables_one of table_two and then add the three new table_one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't try right now but I think you want that:

```
class TableTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :table_two, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**Edit** adding the dependent tag to avoid the foreign key to be nullified instead of destroying the record
Source: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4422973

Comment: Its is saving table_ones without table_two id...
For example, when i put 3 tables_ones to save, this is included in table_one table but without a relation.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, what do you mean by  'when i put 3 tables_ones to save'

Comment: table_two.tables_one = [TableOne.new(<attributes>), TableOne.new(<attributes>, TableOne.new(<attributes>]

Comment: And this command should remove all the existing tables_one of table_two and then add the three new table_one ?

Comment: exactly! Sorry if I could not explain better

Comment: Try to do this: `table_two.tables_one << [TableOne.new(<attributes>), TableOne.new(<attributes>, TableOne.new(<attributes>]  table_two.save`

Comment: That only set `null` in old table_one elements

Comment: Explaining: :dependent => :delete_all also works to update action!